# Selenium webdriver onmouseOver - click() events are not working in virtual machine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-14.04

Im using python with selenium webdriver
my scripts running properly in Ubuntu 14.04 OS, the same script im trying to run in an virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04 OS) which is running on Oracle sunVirtualBox but onMouseOver click() events are not working.

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(userName)
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("send2").click()
element_userDropDown = driver.find_element_by_class_name("className")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_userDropDown).perform()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("link_Text").click()
```

What i need to do inorder to run the scripts in virtual machine?
Manually i can able to test the application properly in that virtual machine and all click events are working.

Comment: Are you using the same selenium package version, same browser and the same browser version?

Comment: im using the same browser version - firefox 33, i dono how to check selenium package version, i install selenium using "sudo pip install selenium"

Comment: There may be difference in Selenium package version. Please check the version in both the machine by using pip command "sudo pip show selenium"

Comment: yes, there is change in the selenium package version, code was running properly in "Version: 2.43.0" but it was not running in "Version: 2.44.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed, code was running properly in "Version: 2.43.0", to fix the issue downgrade the Selenium package on your virtual machine using below pip commands:

First un-install Selenium:

```
sudo pip uninstall selenium
```

Then install the working version - 2.43.0:

```
sudo pip install selenium==2.43.0
```

After this, your code should work on virtual machine also without any issue.